# Does DocuSign login endpoint support "client_credentials" as "grant_type"?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to login to Docusign using OAuth 2.0 with grant_type as client_credentails. However, the code examples do not mention anything of this and the only examples provided are for using OAuth authentication with username and password.

Can someone please confirm if client_credentials grant_type is allowed?

Answer (score 1):

No. I believe client_credentials are from a legacy implementation of OAuth that is no longer supported. Can you can link the documentation/example you're referencing?

Answer (score 0):

No, DocuSign only supports authorization code, JWT, and implicit grant.

For testing and initial development of projects, you can skip the OAuth stage and just plug in an Access Code instead. See the [OAuth Token Generator tool.](https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator)